# Gstreamer pipeline syntax

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I'm learning how to use Gstreamer. I have found this pipeline in some of the tutorials I'm reading

```
gst-launch -v v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! ffmpegcolorspace \
! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240,framerate=(fraction)10/1 \
! theoraenc bitrate=200 ! oggmux \
! tcpclientsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

In the tutorial it said that we create a pipeline like this :

```
gst-launch plugin [parameter=value ]* {! plugin}*
```

I don't understand in the pipeline above this :

```
video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240,framerate=(fraction)10/1
```

It's doesn't respect the syntax and video/x-raw-yuv it's not a plugin.

If it's not a plugin, so how to create it in C/C++ program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's syntactic sugar for the capsfilter element: capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,..."

I see that you're using GStreamer 0.10. It is no longer maintained since more than two years and for new applications you should really consider upgrading to the 1.x versions.